# Controller action to create child view?

Tags: ember.js

Using latest ember.js build, I'm trying to use a controller action to create a childView and push it into the current view. But I can't figure out how to talk to the associated view.

In my search.handlebars:

```
<p>Results:</p>
{{#each animal in someResults}}
  <li><a {{action showAnimal animal}}>{{animal.species.commonName}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

In App.SearchController, I have:

```
showAnimal: function(animal) {
  // Now what?? The below is obviously wrong
  this.animalView = App.AnimalView.create({controller: animal});
  var childView = App.SearchView.createChildView(this.animalView);
  App.SearchView.get('childViews').pushObject(childView);
}
```

The objects visible from within `showAnimal` are:

- `animal` - ok fine
- `this.container` - don't see anything helpful in here
- `this.target` - seemingly the router?

Anyway, I'm baffled. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recognizing my question was a bit arcane / situation specific, here is what I ultimately did in case anyone cares. Note that some APIs have subsequently changed.

Recall that I'm trying to get a jQuery UI dialog to popup in my current view. [Luke Melia's great article on this topic](http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/) was the basis for my original approach.

In handlebars:

```
{{#each animal in someResults}}
  <li><a {{action showAnimal animal target="view" href=true}}>{{animal.species.commonName}} </a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Then in App.SearchView:

```
App.SearchView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'my-appname/~templates/search',
  showAnimal: function(animal) {
    animalDialog = App.AnimalView.create()
    animalDialog.set('context', animal);
    animalDialog.append();
  }
});
```

And just for completeness, here's the AnimalView.

```
App.AnimalView = JQ.Dialog.extend({
  templateName: 'my-appname/~templates/animal',
  autoOpen: true,
  modal: true,
  closeText: "Ok"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using the `{{action}}` instead of the `{{linkTo}}` helper? `{{linkTo}}` would generate a link to the animal passed with the helper. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/.

You can then define a route as described in [the Router API Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).

Comment: I'm trying to embed a jquery ui modal dialog (showing the animal details) on top of the search view, which is already visible. I don't want to transition to a new view.

What I'm trying instead now is using `{{action showAnimal animal}}` with `{{view "App.AnimalView" controllerBinding="selectedAnimal" isVisibleBinding="isAnimalVisible"}}`

Then in the controller, I do `showAnimal: function(animal) { this.set('selectedAnimal', animal); this.set('isAnimalVisible', true);`

Getting some weird behaviors given dialog's separate management of its visibility, but think I can work through them.